# MySQL query with dependent subqueries - how can I speed it up?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I am trying to speed up. I am sure that there is a way to make this more efficient but I have a lack of knowledge.

orders - this shows one row per order received (currently 800,000 rows)

orders_financials - this shows one row per financial transaction associated with the order (currently 2,000,000 rows)

The orders_financials table will contain multiple rows per order, the category of the transaction is shown in financialType

So, for example, for one order there might be 5 rows in orders_financials

```
financialType = 14: value = 10.00
financialType = 12: value = 7.00
financialType = 18: value = 2.50
financialType = 15: value = 0.30
financialType = 17: value = 7.50
```

For each order there will be a varying amount of data. Over time more data is added to the system and new rows are added to orders_financials.

What I am trying to do is to run a query that allows me to get one row per order and for this row to calculate the totals of several categories of financial transactions.

The query below should give me all orders placed by customerID 279:

```
select 
orders.orderID, 
customers.username, 
(select group_concat(financialRef) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (17) ) ref,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (17) ) costs_cost,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (12,13) ) costs_exp,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (14) ) costs_sell,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (15) ) costs_sell_out,                                       
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (1,2,3,9,11) ) extras_in,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (4,5) ) extras_out,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (20) ) extras_back,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (18) ) insurance_in,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (10,6) ) insurance_out,
(select sum(amount) from orders_financials where orders_financials.orderID=orders.orderID and financialType IN (19) ) insurance_back                                            
from orders 
left join customers on orders.customerID=customers.customerID 
where customers.customerID='279'
order by orderID
```

(FYI, there are 18,263 records in the orders table where customerID=279)

You'll see that financialType's of 12 or 13 can be totalled to come up with costs_exp. Likewise 1,2 3,9,11 are all extras_in.

The end result is a nice query with a lot of data but it gives a detailed overview for every order. In the where clause I can search by customer, by service, by date range, etc.

My problem is that this query takes *ages* to run. I must be doing it in a very inefficient way as each element of the query individually is fast.

From slow log I can see it's iterating through 422,000,000 rows

```
Query_time: 528.107584  Lock_time: 0.000652 Rows_sent: 1388  Rows_examined: 422442417
```

There must be a more efficient way but I am struggling to see.

EDIT - Here is the EXPLAIN of the above query:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table             | type  | possible_keys         | key           | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | customers         | const | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY       | 4       | const                     |      1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | orders            | ref   | customerID            | customerID    | 5       | const                     |  24802 | Using where; Using index |
| 12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |      1 | Using where              |
| 11 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | range | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | NULL                      |      2 | Using where              |
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |  49717 | Using where              |
|  9 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |      1 | Using where              |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | range | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | NULL                      |      2 | Using where              |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | range | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | NULL                      |      5 | Using where              |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |    139 | Using where              |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | orderID       | 4       | p4db_admin.orders.orderID | 236338 | Using where              |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | orderID       | 4       | p4db_admin.orders.orderID | 236338 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |  99966 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders_financials | ref   | orderID,financialType | financialType | 4       | const                     |  99966 | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: show us explain of that query. Also subquery in mysql is generally a very slow and painful thing so if you are going to use them a lot consider switching to mariadb.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Try adding a composite index on `(orderID,financialType,financialRef,amount)`, and then both your query and the rewrite by @491243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.orderID, 
        b.username,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 17 THEN c.financialRef END) ref,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType IN (12,13) THEN c.amount END) costs_cost,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 14 THEN c.amount END) costs_exp,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 15 THEN c.amount END) costs_sell,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType IN (1,2,3,9,11) THEN c.amount END) extras_in,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType IN (4,5) THEN c.amount END) extras_out,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 20 THEN c.amount END) extras_back,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 18 THEN c.amount END) insurance_in,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType IN (10,6) THEN c.amount END) insurance_out,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.financialType = 19 THEN c.amount END) insurance_back
FROM    orders a
        LEFT JOIN customers b
            ON a.customerID = b.customerID 
        LEFT JOIN orders_financials c
            ON a.orderID = c.orderID
GROUP   BY a.orderID, b.username
```

add also index on `orders_financials.financialType`

```
ALTER TABLE orders_financials ADD INDEX (financialType)
```

Comment: Just one more question thought. In orders_financials there might be 10 rows for a particular orderID. One of these will be a financialType 10 and this has a corresponding carrierInvoiceID of 12345

How can I add a WHERE query to get all orderID from orders_financial where the financialType=10 and carrierInvoiceID=12345 and then for all orderIDs found to be displayed in my table and the dynamically calculated totals to be shown?

I was using:

a.orderID IN (select orderID from orders_financials where carrierInvoiceID='12345')

But this is taking ages, I assume there is a better way @491243

Comment: `LEFT JOIN orders_financials c
            ON a.orderID = c.orderID AND c.carrierInvoiceID='12345'` -- is that what you want? not sure.

Comment: If I run 

    SELECT orderID FROM orders_financials WHERE financialType =  '17' AND carrierInvoiceID =  '230' 

then I get 1864 records. I just want those 1864 orderIDs to be the ones that are queried and I get the totals of the various cost groups. Hope this makes sense @491243